# Getting error "AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.1-7396180-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed"

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I updated android Arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 1.

build tools version com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1

My gradle version https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip

please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is detailed error i m geetting:

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.3-7396180-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
     Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.